# Why doesn't str() use __getattribute__ to get __str__ and how to produce the effect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattribute, python-datamodel

When I call `str()` on an object that has an overloaded `__getattribute__` method it doesn't seem to use it and instead calls `__str__` directly. Is there some other functionality I should be modifying or way to get it to use `__getattribute__`? If I overload `__str__` directly it behaves as expected, but that isn't ideal for my needs.

```
class A(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == "__str__":
            return lambda: "Hello"
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

x = A()

print(x)
print(str(x))
print(x.__str__())
```

Output: 
<**main**.A object at 0x000001FDF7AEA760> 
<**main**.A object at 0x000001FDF7AEA760> 
Hello

Expected Output: 
Hello 
Hello 
Hello

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is [documented behavior](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

> This method may still be bypassed when looking up special methods as
>   the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or built-in
>   functions.

And [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup):

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only
>   guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in
>   the object’s instance dictionary
>
> ...
>
> In addition to bypassing any instance attributes in the interest of
>   correctness, implicit special method lookup generally also bypasses
>   the `__getattribute__()` method even of the object’s metaclass...
>
> ...

As to *why*:

> Bypassing the `__getattribute__()` machinery in this fashion provides
>   significant scope for speed optimisations within the interpreter, at
>   the cost of some flexibility in the handling of special methods (the
>   special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be
>   consistently invoked by the interpreter).

Comment: Thanks a ton! That's a great explanation! Does this mean the only reasonable way would be to overload `__str__` and any other special methods I would want to implement this way?

Comment: @RedKnite yes, that's what it means.